# I've a small problem with the declaration of a function "declaration is incompatible with", and "different basic types"

Tags: c, compiler-errors, return-type, function-declaration

I was writing a C program. This C program has to compute the solutions of a quadratic equation. The problem is that debugger showed me this kind of errors: "E0147", and "C22371".
this is my program:

delta.c:

```
    #include "delta.h"
    #include "math.h"

    double delta(double a, double b, double c) {
    double delta = 0; 
    double power = pow(b, b); 
    delta = power - (4 * a * c); 
    return delta; 
}
```

delta.h:

```
#if !defined DELTA_H
#define DELTA_H  

extern double delta(double a, double b, double c); 

#endif /* DELTA_H */
```

solutions.c:

```
#include "delta.h"
#include "solutions.h" 
#include "math.h"

double solutions (double a, double b, double c, double* x1, double* x2) {
double checking_the_delta = 0; 
checking_the_delta = delta(a, b, c); 
if (checking_the_delta == 0) {
    return 1; 
}
else if (checking_the_delta >= 0) {
    double tmp = delta(a, b, c);
    double square_root = sqrt(tmp);
    *x1 = (-b + square_root) / 2;
    *x2 = (-b - square_root) / 2;
}
else 
    return 0; 
}
```

solutions.h:

```
#if !defined SOLUTIONS_H 

#define SOLUTIONS_H

extern solutions(double a, double b, double c, double* x1, double* 
x2); 

#endif /* SOLUTIONS_H */
```

and finally, the main.c:

```
#include "solutions.h" 
#include "delta.h" 

int main(void) {
solutions(...); 
return 0; 
}
```

---

the problem is in this line: "double solutions (double a, double b, double c, double* x1, double* x2)". the debugger said this declaration is incompatible with the declaration in the header file. Moreover, it said that "solutions redefinition: different basic types".

I'm completely lost, I've written the declarations again but debugger keeps showing me these two errors.

Comment: Can you post the solutions.h file?

Comment: ah, I forgot it. Thanks. Give me 1 second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the function `solutions` returns nothing in case when `checking_the_delta > 0` though the function return type is not `void`.

```
double solutions (double a, double b, double c, double* x1, double* x2) {
double checking_the_delta = 0; 
checking_the_delta = delta(a, b, c); 
if (checking_the_delta == 0) {
    return 1; 
}
else if (checking_the_delta >= 0) {
    double tmp = delta(a, b, c);
    double square_root = sqrt(tmp);
    *x1 = (-b + square_root) / 2;
    *x2 = (-b - square_root) / 2;
}
else 
    return 0; 
}
```

Also this declaration

```
double tmp = delta(a, b, c);
```

is redundant because the variable `checking_the_delta` already contains the result of the function call `delta(a, b, c)`

```
checking_the_delta = delta(a, b, c);
```

Secondly in the function declaration in the header you forgot to specify the return type `double` as in the function definition

```
extern soluzioni(double a, double b, double c, double* x1, double* 
x2);
```

Pay attention to that the function actually returns an integer instead of a double value. So maybe you need to specify the return type `int`.

Answer (score 3):

`extern solutions(double a, double b, double c, double* x1, double*  x2);` fails to specify the return type of `solutions`. Typically, it will default to `int`, for reasons related to the history of C.

Then this is incompatible with `double solutions (double a, double b, double c, double* x1, double* x2)` because the latter declares the return type to be `double`.

Fix the declarations so they declare the same return type in both place: You might insert `double` after `extern` in the header declaration. However, it looks like the function is intended to return the number of distinct solutions. In that case, you may want to make the return type `int` in both places, and insert `return 2;` in the code that processes two solutions.